# How do I set mask for RadMaskedTextBox to accept all characters without format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a RadMaskedTextBox in usercontrol and i change it's mask in page load to accept date or money or integer or string.
(For example :

> txt.Mask= "###,###,###,###";//for money
>   txt.Mask= "####/##/##";//for date

)

For each item i could change the mask except string,I don't know how to set mask for string(to accept all words and numbers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accept any character at a given position in your mask, you'd use the placeholder **a**.
This is right in [Telerik's documentation on mask behavior](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-maskedtextbox-masks.html):

> Mask element *a*:  Accepts any character. If this position is blank in the mask, it is
>   rendered as a prompt character.

On the other hand, if what you're looking for is to completely disable the mask feature in certain circumstances, you'll have to add an alternate control, such as RadTextBox, and enable it instead.  This is mentioned [in a thread in the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/input/radmaskedtextbox-without-mask.aspx).  For Silverlight and WPF, the RadMaskedTextBox control has a property "MaskType" that can be set to None to disable the mask, but the ASP.Net version of the control doesn't have this.